# Making log files in NiFi

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

I want to make log files for each processors in NiFi. I use `splitText` for splitting log files and then processing them after it I have one log message distribute in 5 files. I want to keep this data and write it in one  log file for each processor (for example I use  this expression fro getting executescript processor`${regex:toLower():contains('executescript')}`).

1. How can I write this logs in one log file for each processor?
2. Should I use any native NiFi processor or make it by Groovy code?

Is it possible to get flowfile data I used this but processor seems to have bad response:

```
def flowFile1 = session.create();
def flowFile=session.get();

while(flowFile != null){
    flowFile1 = session.write(flowFile, {outputStream -> def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(flowFile) 
    outputStream.write(builder.toPrettyString().getBytes(Standar‌​dCharsets.UTF_8)) } as OutputStreamCallback) 
}

flowFile1 = session.putAttribute(flowFile,'filename','ExecuteScriptLog')
session.remove(flowFile);
session.transfer(flowFile1, REL_SUCCESS)
```

I have  WorkFlow  ike thi and i wnat to get  connection name for example  'executescrip't and  make  flowfile  with this name and  input all flowfile  data  whcih  is  placed inside this  'executescript'  queue and write  it in one  file  created  by me (in  this case  'executescript')
[image]

Comment: is it  possible to  get  connection name  and  then name  flowfile according to it ? i want  to make it  because  i use   routeonattribute and   have named  onnection by prosesor names

Comment: also  i want  to know  if it is   possible to get  flowilfe data  and  put it into  json

Answer (score 1):

the logging configuration you can manage through `NIFI_HOME/conf/logback.xml` file.

you can define here logging files (appenders) and what messages should be logged.

the logback manual: https://logback.qos.ch/manual/index.html

each processor has a classname that you can see on the screen (ex:`org.apache.nifi.processors.attributes.UpdateAttribute`) - 
you need this info to configure logger in logback.xml and direct it to appender (file)

also you can define filtering in the logback.xml for each appender
so that only messages that matches regexp will be appended into into it.

Comment: can i make one  flowfie   for each processsor type  for exmple  make  flowfile called invokehttp and  write  here all inovkehttp logs? (  i mean nifi -app  logs)

Comment: is it possible to  do it inside  one executescript  code by  groovy   code?